# How to find rank?

Tags: linear-algebra

If M is a $7 \times 5$ matrix of rank $3$ and $N$ is a $5 \times 7$ matrix of rank $5$ , then $\text{rank}(MN)$ is?

The far I get is that $\text{rank}(MN)$ should be less than $\text{min}(\text{rank} M, \text{rank} N)$.
Don't know how to proceed further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$N$ maps a seven dimensional space to a five dimensional space. Its rank is $5$ so it is surjective. Thus the rank of $MN$ is again $3$.